# Where is the appropriate place to ask about Shahab al-Din Yahya ibn Habash Suhrawardi, cited as founder of the philosophy of illuminationism?

Tags: support

This is the gentleman I am referencing:--

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shahab_al-Din_Yahya_ibn_Habash_Suhrawardi)

This is an example of his philosophy and/or theology:--

> "Whoever knows philosophy (hikmat) and perseveres in thanking and sanctifying the Light of the Lights, will be endowed with royal glory (kharreh) and with luminous splendor (farreh), and—as we have said elsewhere—divine light will further bestow upon him the cloak of royal power and value. Such a person shall then become the natural ruler of the universe. He shall be given aid from the high heavens, and whatever he commands shall be obeyed; and his dreams and inspirations will reach their uppermost, perfect pinnacle." [English]
>
> "و هر که حکمت بداند و بر سپاس و تقدیس نور الانوار مداومت نماید، او را خرّه کیانی بدهند و فرّ نورانی ببخشند، و بارقی الاهی او را کسوت هیبت و بهاء بپوشاند و رئیس طبیعی شود عالم را، و او را از عالم اعلا نصرت رسد و سخن او در عالم علوی مسموع باشد، و خواب و الهام او به کمال رسد." [Translated from Old Persian; not modern Farsi or modern Arabic]
>
> -- Hossein Ziai, "The book of radiance", Mazda Publisher, 1998. pg 84-85. Note that Ziai, whose extensive studies establish Suhrawardi as a rationalist thinker rather than an "Oriental mystic" translates the word Hikmat (wisdom) as "philosophy" rather than "wisdom," as is more common.

---

**Notable References/Comments**:--

- (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divine_light)
- (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohr)
- (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inward_light)
- (https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/suhrawardi/)
- (https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/illumination/)
- (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Fox)

[Various famous figures, ranging from Joe Biden (whose style is eerily similar to this) to Eckhart Tolle†, have written about this.](https://twitter.com/Pontifex/status/1073918092470829058)

I prefer to keep this focused on, but not limited to, *secular morality*. I am very serious, because there is a void where secular morality should be in our Human Society.

---

I should clarify I am much more interested in Zoroastrianism, and relatively less in Islam. --[This is not a comment on the nature of Islam.]--

In which Stack Exchange website should he be discussed? Is this appropriate for the Philosophy Stack Exchange?

---

† who was accepted into Cambridge (but dropped out), and has given talks at Google

Comment: Reads like metaphysics and categorically *not* philosophy.

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy

Hello, my friend. You are welcome to disagree in respectful and civil terms.

I am however confused by your usage of the term, metaphysics, as most people would regard metaphysics as a subset of philosophy.

Comment: Philosophers do not argue about imponderable claims; metaphysicians do. Metaphysics are not philosophy, and this because philosophy is "love of wisdom", not "love of metaphysical speculation", not "love of hermeneutics", not "love of dialectic." Wisdom requires knowledge, not opinion, belief or personal view, else how does one "know" who or what is wise?

Comment: see also: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/42076/23399

Comment: (https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/metaphysics)

Comment: And what is the knowledge obtained or hypothesis advanced by _"Whoever knows philosophy (hikmat) and perseveres in thanking and sanctifying the Light of the Lights, will be endowed with royal glory (kharreh) and with luminous splendor (farreh), and—as we have said elsewhere—divine light will further bestow upon him the cloak of royal power and value"_? Hint: none.

Comment: See this post here:

(https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3697/30380)

Comment: Feel free to expand your comments into a full answer, so long as the answer complies with Stack Exchange's standards, and is of high-quality; etc., etc.

Comment: I'll stop this discussion here.

Comment: Thank you for your civil input.

Comment: @TautologicalRevelations - You are right to question the separation of metaphysics from philosophy. They are the same thing. I have no idea how a person could do philosophy but not metaphysics. I don't know anywhere on SE you can discuss this philosopher. You could discuss his metaphysical view on Philosophy SE if you can extract it from his flowery presentation. He does not appear to be theist and seems to be promoting the perennial message of mysticism, which may be found in Zoroastrianism. You may not be looking into Islam but keep an eye out for Sufism.  .

Comment: He is referenced in the SEP. (https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/suhrawardi/) (https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/arabic-islamic-mysticism/)

Comment: @PeterJ Thank you for your input. I'll consider what you have to say. It is true that he does not fit 100% into any Stack Exchange website, but we can still try our best to find the best website for this. I supplied two sources in my previous comment from Western Canon philosophy.

Comment: @PeterJ "[...] ... if you can extract it from his flowery presentation. [...]" ~  PeterJ This is a legitimate concern.

Comment: Joe Biden's rhetoric is eerily similar to mine and the folks I've cited:--

(https://www.politico.com/news/2020/08/20/biden-i-will-be-an-ally-of-the-light-not-the-darkness-399738)

I'm not sure whether to add this source or not. Shall the question be improved in such a way?

Comment: It's nice to see Eckhart Tolle (who has given talks at Google) joining the party: < https://beingthelight.eckharttolle.com/awaken_your_inner_light_free_mini_series42533397 >. I'll make small modifications to update the question to make it more relevant to my new comments, later. However, the content shall remain ~95% the same, with the same focus on filling the void of where "secular morality should be in Human Society." I'll make improvements to the question, akin to: < https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/3696/revisions >.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the Wikipedia article and the quote are correct, I see nothing wrong in exploring his writings in the context of Philosophy.SE:

He seemingly argued for a cosmology, including some kind of a monistic ontology (emanation from the light of lights - somewhat similar to Spinoza but with more of an idealistic flavour), and critically commented on Avicenna. This is philosophical metaphysics, even if it may be in context of and reference to theological considerations. This is simply how philosophy at that time looked like everywhere (more precisely: where Abrahamic religions were prevalent) and I cannot see how it is much different from the philosophy of e.g. the Christian St. Thomas Aquinas or especially the Judaic Kabbalah.

That being said: As long as the question and its answers can be based on English translations, it should be perfectly fine to ask about the specifically philosophical aspects of his work. The more this goes from philosophical considerations towards the specific questions of how to interpret, say, Allah in the light of Qur'an (or other religious texts) according to the cosmology developed, this becomes more of a borderline case, as this tips into specifically theological considerations.

Comment: This comment promptly resolved the issue. So, I'm going to mark this question as answered. TY for your input. :) :D

Comment: Your concerns are good. Thank you for answering. :) ^^ :D 